# Some functions don't work when using two databases in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration

I'm working on migrating one WP site to a new one. Both are rather advanced with many custom fields, taxonomies and post types so I can't use the built in plugins for importing/exporting.

Instead I've set up both databases on the same server and can easily switch between them using `$wpdb->select('old_db_name')` and `$wpdb->select(DB_NAME)`. I've created a tiny plugin for this so that it runs from inside WP and thus allows me to use all the WP-methods for fetching and inserting posts etc.

Everything works fine except for one thing; taxonomies. All the functions I've tried that are related to taxonomies will query the `DB_NAME` database (i.e. the one the WP installation is running from).

Here's a simple example:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

# Use default DB
$wpdb->select(DB_NAME);

# Prints "2" (I've only added two posts to the new installation)
echo count(get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1)));
# Prints all the taxonomies
var_dump(get_taxonomies());

# Switch to old DB
$wpdb->select('old_db_name');

# Prints > "300" (there are roughly 300 posts in the old DB - the number is correct and NOT the same as before)
echo count(get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1)));
# Prints EXACTLY the same thing as the previous call, even though the old DB has different custom taxonomies
var_dump(get_taxonomies());
```

`wp_get_post_terms()` doesn't work either but instead queries the new DB (if I try to fetch the terms from an old taxonomy that no longer exists in the new DB WP throws an error saying that the taxonomy doesn't exist).

Is this a bug? Any way to solve it? There's not much info about using more than one DB in WP so haven't been able to find anything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after hours of investigation it seems that WP caches all the available taxonomies on initialization, so when switching DB it **will not** re-check available taxonomies. It *does* however select data from the correct DB so that was not the issue.

The solution I came up with was simply adding the missing taxonomies to the new DB (temporarily), and after the migration I'll just remove them.